# How Call Certain Lov on a specific Condition in Oracle APEX 5.1?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

```
IF :P123_Type = 'C' THEN
  RETURN    
     LOV_1  
ELSE    
  RETURN    
     LOV_2  
END IF;
```

I Have 2 Shared Component's LOVs & want to achieve like above. How to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

Shared Component LOVs are accessible through the `apex_application_lovs` view.

```
DESC apex_application_lovs

Name                   Null     Type           
---------------------- -------- -------------- 
WORKSPACE              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255)  
WORKSPACE_DISPLAY_NAME          VARCHAR2(4000) 
APPLICATION_ID         NOT NULL NUMBER         
APPLICATION_NAME       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255)  
LIST_OF_VALUES_NAME    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255)  
LOV_TYPE                        VARCHAR2(7)    
LIST_OF_VALUES_QUERY            VARCHAR2(4000) 
LOV_ENTRIES                     NUMBER         
IS_SUBSCRIBED                   VARCHAR2(3)    
SUBSCRIBED_FROM                 VARCHAR2(297)  
LAST_UPDATED_BY                 VARCHAR2(255)  
LAST_UPDATED_ON                 DATE           
COMPONENT_COMMENT               VARCHAR2(4000) 
LOV_ID                 NOT NULL NUMBER         
REFERENCED_LOV_ID               NUMBER         
COMPONENT_SIGNATURE             VARCHAR2(436)
```

So you could set the list of values on your Select List item on your page to **PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query**.
As function body you can use something like:

```
DECLARE
  ret apex_application_lovs.list_of_values_query%TYPE;
BEGIN
  IF :P123_Type = 'C' THEN
    select list_of_values_query 
      into ret
      from apex_application_lovs 
     where list_of_values_name = 'LOV_1';
  ELSE    
    select list_of_values_query  
      into ret
      from apex_application_lovs 
     where list_of_values_name = 'LOV_2';
  END IF;

  return ret;
END;
```

If `P123_TYPE` can be altered dynamically and this list is a cascading list, you will need to add the item to items to be submitted to session state as the list is refreshed.

Comment: would be much better to not use IDs: exporting and importing such as a move to production may completely alter the ID. Hardcoding IDs is never a good idea. The lovs view instead has columns such as application id and the list_of_values_name, allowing full flexibility. Furthermore, you could define the `ret` variable with `%TYPE` on the selected column of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Create two items based in each of your LOVs and then condition their display to only show one of them depending of your requirements.
- Forget your Shared Component LOVs and use a function to return the query you want to use in your LOV (with one item only and without display condition). Something like:

  ```
  function f_get_lov(p_condition in number)
  return varchar2 as
      l_sql varchar2(4000);
  begin
      if p_condition = 1 then
    -- query lov_1
        l_sql := 'select display_value
                  ,      return_value
                    from tb1';
      else
        -- query lov 2
        l_sql := 'select display_value
                  ,      return_value
                    from tb2';
      end if;

      return l_sql;
  end f_get_lov;
  ```

Comment: creating two items has drawbacks and issues though. For instance, when the source is a database column you won't be able to create more than one such item, meaning you'd need an intermediary and computations to set its value. If using conditions it can't be dynamic either. The second option would be much more feasible. A package with statements would serve just as well as a "shared component". One small note: the heavy indents all serve as a bunch of extra lost whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a dynamic lov based on a function? This is different than what Boris has suggested since it does not require you to create a function outside of APEX, but instead just another LOV.

```
Declare 
  v_type varchar2(1) := :P123_TYPE;
 Begin
  If v_type = 'C' then
    Return 'select column_a d, column_b r
                   from some_table
                  where some_column = ''CONDITION 1'';
  Else
     Return 'select column_a d, column_b r
                   from some_table
                  where some_column = ''CONDITION 2'';
  End if;
End;
```

*notice how I've doubled up on the single quotes to escape them; you could chose to escape these characters a different way if desired..*